# Re-broadcasting a wideband satellite television signal over a short distance?

Tags: rf, transmitter, coax

Normally a coax cable connects a satellite dish to the receiver. I'm in a situation where I can't easily install a coax cable, but a wireless signal ought to be possible because it's only 10 meters through a wooden house (no steel or concrete), but not line-of-sight.

I'm wondering whether a device exists or if it's possible to design a device that can wirelessly send the raw satellite signal to a receiver? Would something like [this product](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Emprex-AWV-699B-5-8ghz-Wireless-Sender/dp/B0035FCT5Q/ref=tag_stp_s2_edpp_url) work?

Note that I'm interested in "wirelessifying" the connection *to* the sat receiver. I don't want to distribute the signal coming *out of* the receiver toward the TV set.

```
[sat dish] ... [wireless signal??] ... [receiver*)] ... [HDMI] ... [projector]
```

My receiver is not a separate box, I've got a Windows Media Center PC with two internal tuner cards that can accept DVB-S. A ceiling projector is attached to the PC by HDMI cable, and that's how I watch TV and anything else.

Comment: I don't think I'll solder this myself but was indeed asking whether any such product -- or product category -- exists at all. While that's not a direct product-recommendation question, I see that it's close enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you transmit the signal using your '5.4GHz video transmitter'?

Apart from the very good points Andy raised about having to supply power to the transmitter etc. If you look at what comes out of the LNB you have a baseband signal of over 1GHz to try and re-transmit. A video transmitter has no chance.

[image]

Comment: Ah, so you're saying that the coax copper transmits _all_ the frequencies _all_ the time -- then I understand why a wireless replacement is not practically possible, except for NASA :-)

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun Yes, the coax transfers all the channels as a baseband with each  separate channel having defined frequency and bandwidths (frequency multiplexing). The receiver then selects the one it wants and decodes it.

Answer (score 2):

Satellite dishes usually have a low-noise signal amplifier built in. This is normally phantom-powered through the coax cable. In those instances (and I'm not aware of any other types for T.V.) you need that cable. Don't scrimp when it comes to this sort of thing!

Apart from anything else you'd still need to supply power to the dish to re-transmit your signal and this would need a cable.

Comment: So you're saying that the sat receiver powers the dish's LNB antenna via coax? That makes sense. Could it not be powered through the "coax wireless transmitter" that I hope exists? Clearly _something_ needs to be attached to the LNB, and that something would power the LNB just as the receiver would.

Comment: You'll still need a cable to bring power to the dish's location or, are you thinking of solar panels/battery? Be also aware that the full bandwidth of the signal from the dish may be wider than any commercial transmitter/receiver you can find - all channels occupy a large band of the spectrum and simultaneously they are all sent down the coax and it is the T.V.'s tuner (or set-top box) that selects the channel you choose locally in your lounge or bedroom.

Comment: Not solar; I was thinking that the wireless setup would require a transmitter connected to the LNB, and that transmitter would operate on regular 220V from a nearby socket.